# How can i stop wearOS physical button default functionality for home action

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, hardware, home-button

i am working on project which is base on WearOs app development , This app content small game and in this i want to disable default functionality of physical button 1(Home or lock) and button 2(back press), here i don't have a issue to handle button 2 where in button 1 ,I  cant bypass functionality of button 1 and want to give my custom action with button 1 get pressed but i am not getting any way to do this and i am using samsung watch 4 which is working on TizenOS support wearOs ,Even i give permission for deviceAdministration to do so and i custom that button 1 functionality to lock instead of home and this is working , but now i want to stop that complete and want to get event of button press in my wearOs app to perform some custom action , hope you got me what i want to perform, let me know your thought on this if possible to achieve in Tizen OS and other all watch on power button press , if possible please help me how can i achieve this and if not then please give me a details reason for same
Thanks in advance for support .

Also i refer google doc which give me a demo for using physical button Link: "https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/physical-buttons#metadata" but not working for me in samsung watch 4

Comment: You can it override that button ever.